# PreLoad UIWebView on a not yet displayed UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, load

I have an app where on the very last UIViewController there is a UIWebView... the user navigates through the app and at the very end they can transition (modal) to the final UIViewController with a UIWebView... in it's viewDidLoad I have the UIWebView load the page.

The problem is it takes about 8 seconds to load this page and that annoys users.

How can I load the UIWebView way ahead of time (like when the app is first launched!) if that UIViewController hasn't even been presented yet?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had your same problem for UIWebView inside a UIPageViewController and I found a better solution.

If you are in `FirstViewController` and you have your webView in your `SecondViewController` put the `loadHTMLString` or  `loadRequest` method in the `viewDidLoad` of your `SecondViewController` and call `[secondViewController.view layoutSubviews]` for start loading in your `FirstViewController`.

Ex:

**FirstViewController**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // _secondViewController -> An instance of SecondVieController
    [_secondViewController.view layoutSubviews];
}
```

**SecondViewController**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.it"];
    NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: AWESOME!!! I searched for hours and didn't find a solution. Really nice trick! :)

Comment: I know this is old but wanted to know if you might be able to translate this to swift? Thanks

Comment: @dwinnbrown no I didn't, but should be not difficult to do it, calling the same methods with swift instead of objective-c

Comment: @dwinnbrown as apple suggest, instead of call layoutSubviews, is better to call:
[_secondViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
[_secondViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: Great job! Thanks for the help

Comment: Thank for the answer - this will enable completely new solution approaches for my app (i.e. by using more Javascript libraries for common problems like beautiful signature captures or PDF export).

Comment: This isn't working for me in Xcode 8, it calls the "viewDidLoad" on the second view controller as I can see that in the logs. However it doesn't appear to trigger the webView loading. I never see the delegate methods for the webView triggered and also when I switch to the 2nd controller I still have to wait for the page to load? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

What u can do is, load the html string

```
 NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.path ofType:@"htm"];
 NSError * error;
 NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

and when u display the webView load this content in your webView

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

then your webview need only render your content and doesn't load the data

/// In Swift 2.0

```
    do{
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("theName", ofType: "html")!
        let html = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }catch{
        print("Error is happend")
    }
```

Note: It works the same way for WKWebView

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much work you want to do for this but I think you could cache/store the data from the URL in something like a NSDictionary, or something similar, using `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` and use that information before actually loading the page.

So, load the first time you use it, after it has been seen then store the data using NSUserDefaults. Next time you go to this page, load from the NSUserDefaults first and call the URL/API in the back ground then update NSUserDefaults with this new data.

If you are requesting or pulling specific information each time, then I don't think this will work. If that is your case, you can probably try loading the data/website in an earlier view controller (probably one that takes the user a while to navigate to) and then send that data to the webview. Something like delegate/protocol or maybe even NSNotificationCenter. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

`UIWebView` is very tricky object. Simple answer would be: no you can't.

`UIWebView` won't load a document or an URL if it is not in views hierarchy.
Don't try doing it in different thread/queue either.

What you can do is to add `UIWebView` to the views hierarchy at the very beginning (as you've mentioned) and then pass it to the last view controller with preloaded data. This may work, but it's not an elegant way.

Side questions is: why does it take 8 secs to load a page? Maybe you can download the content of this page earlier? Is it static or dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic /: The website is very graphic heavy.