# Preloading of UIwebview in IOS?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I had an Iphone application in which i need to load a webview with google as the default page.It start loading only when it is visible,But i need to preload the google.com at the start of the application in that webview.I tried to create a Uiwebview in appdelegate and tried it to pass it to the actual one.But seems to be not working .

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

[webview loadRequest:request];
```

i was also tried to call this in another function and tried to call that function from the app delegate.but seems to be not loading?can anybody help me on this to figure it out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563801/preload-uiwebview-on-a-not-yet-displayed-uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Add to the view hierarchy, set alpha / hidden to be not visible (or cover it completely with another view), then show it on the callback [**`webViewDidFinishLoad:`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad%3a).

It won't load anything unless it is added to the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad]; 
            [objWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html><body style=\"background-color:red;\"></body></html>" baseURL:nil];


            [self performSelector:@selector(URLdata:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1]; 
        }

    -(void)URLdata:(id)sender{
        [objWebView stopLoading]; 
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gmail.com"];
        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [objWebView loadRequest:req];
    }
```